# 410 error code obtained while uploading file

Tags: google-drive-api

Google Drive REST API v3.

I use resumable upload for uploading files of any size. If I encounter any problem while uploading a file, I wait for exponential backoff, then ask current upload session for the byte range and then continue from the last uploaded byte. This process repeats up to 5 times. If the file was not uploaded successfully after all, I write an error to a log.

Unfortunately, I did not logged all the intermediate errors, so all I have is that the last error was "410, description: Internal Error".

The file was less than 1Kb and the whole process took about 17s before the error was logged.

My case is very similar to the one described in question [Google Drive Api Upolading File Error with error code 500 Inernal server error and 410 Gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492412/google-drive-api-upolading-file-error-with-error-code-500-inernal-server-error-a), but I do use exponential backoff, so the upload session token could not expire. Additionally, it is not "410 Gone", but "410 Internal Error".

I want to know what could cause "410 Internal Error" and how should I react to it.

Comment: I hope I can trace it in Fiddler or at least log all the intermediate errors on the clients side, so that the question was more precise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Drive Api Upolading File Error with error code 500 Inernal server error and 410 Gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492412/google-drive-api-upolading-file-error-with-error-code-500-inernal-server-error-a)

Comment: 410 Internal Error and 410 Gone are the same thing.    The resource you are trying access does not exist.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for the note about 410 names. I want to find out any other possible cases for this Google Drive response except for too long timeout between requests, as it was in the similar question

Comment: you are not the only one using the server you are connected to.   It could very easily be something someone else is doing that effects the time of your requests.   There is no way to know.

Comment: @DaImTo could you please advice me what should I do when I encounter 410 error? I could start a new upload session and try to upload that file once again but it is a really bad idea as the file is actually a stream, read from elsewhere in chunks (piece by piece).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted [DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) for details about my question. The response that I receieved contains all the answers that I was looking for, so I think it would be helpful to post it here.

> Once you get a 410 error there is nothing you can do besides start over.    410 error means that what ever you were doing is gone the request resource has been removed from the server.   So trying again where you were with the upload wont help because everything you had uploaded is gone.
>
> It can sometimes be caused by speed issues so if you are on a bad wifi connection and trying to upload it will fail and the server will remove all traces of it.    You also need to remember that you are not the only one hitting Googles servers if someone else is hitting the same server you are on and doing something heavy it can effect you.     The best way to avoid that is to not run anything on the hour and not to run at midnight west cost USA time this is when Googles servers are most busy.