# Google drive API is giving 500 internal server error

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, http-status-code-500

I have tried below code to download files from google drive

```
String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId)
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Some files are getting downloaded few files are not getting downloaded(It was working few days back). I am getting this error.

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}

at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1072)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpDownloader.java:245)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:199)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:562)
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Get.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(Drive.java:3256)
```

Comment: What type is the file that you're trying to download when the error is thrown?

Comment: zip files I am downloading, for some zip files its working for some it is not. And there is no special about not downloading files when compared with downloaded files

Comment: Could be file size? Although as it's 500 it's likely just an intermittant issue server side. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493216/11551468) for tips&tricks

Comment: Not the file size, file with bigger size is also getting downloaded

Comment: I have tried exponentioal Backoff already, it did not help

Comment: Does it occur with seemingly random files or the same files specifically? If you try to download that file on its own do you still get the same error?

Comment: I am able to  download that file manually. It occurs randomly. but it is very frequent

Comment: We started facing this issue since a month, before that everything was fine. I wrote to google guys, but I did not get any response.

Comment: We regularly run into this problem and for a google API it occurs quite often. Don't have a clue yet how to fix this...